# override admin panel layout and phtml in magento2.4.5

Tags: layout, phtml, custom-theme, vendor, magento2.4.5

I want to override adminhtml layout and phtml file of vendor directory to my custom theme so how can I do that, if anyone have idea then please share.

> "Because sharing is caring"

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To override Admin layout/phtml, either you need to create Admin theme or module

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?

Comment: yes magrnto 2.4.5 is running fine. you can use for your site.